# How to encapsulate single and temporal events in a service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, dom-events

I'm trying to encapsulate the events in a service in order to implement a mechanics to subscribe / unsubscribe the listeners when a controller's scope is destroyed. This because I have been using the `rootScope.$on` in the following way:

```
if(!$rootScope.$$listeners['event']) {
    $rootScope.$on('event', function(ev, data){
        // do some...
    });
}
```

or

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(ev, data){
    // unsubscribe the listener
});
```

So I just need one listener of this event, I need to delete the existing listener when the controller is no longer alive, because the function I registered earlier is still being triggered.

So I need to implement a `$destroy` event listener on my controller, to destroy the listener when the scope is destroyed, but I don't want to do that code each time I create an event.
That's why I want to create a service in where I'm going to encapsulate the events.

```
angular.module('core').factory('event', [
    function() {
        var service = {};
        service.events = {};
        service.on = function(scope, eventId, callback) {
            scope.$on('$destroy', function(ev, other){
                //unsubscribe
            });
            service.events[eventId] = callback;
            // scope = null; I guess ?
        };
        service.emit = function(eventId, data){
            if (service.events[eventId])
                service.events[eventId](data);
            else
                return new Error('The event is not subscribed');
        };
        return service;
    }
]);
```

This could be done using **$rootScope** instead of my own methods but encapsulating the `$on` and `$emit` of **$rootScope**, but at the end I'll have the same issue here.

So these are my questions:

1. Is a good practice to pass the scope ref value to a service?
2. What is the meaning of `$$destroyed`? when this is true means that angularJS has no internal references to the instance?
3. Should I do a **scope** = null in my service to let GC delete the object or does angularJS handle an explicit delete?
4. Is there a better way to do what I want?

Comment: what's with the "!!!" ?

Comment: @dandavis I'm using === in all the project so I'm using !! to casting falsy values, here I was rushed and negates again.. I know.. just ! is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is basically an **event bus**. 
 
You have also described very well what is wrong with the current implementation.
A different way to approach the problem is to decorate the $rootScope with your bus (or any other event bus for that matter). Here is how:

```
app.config(function ($provide) {
$provide.decorator('$rootScope', ['$delegate', '$$bus', function ($delegate, $$bus) {
  Object.defineProperty($delegate.constructor.prototype, '$bus', {
    get: function () {
      var self = this;

      return {
        subscribe: function () {
          var sub = $$bus.subscribe.apply($$bus, arguments);

          self.$on('$destroy',
            function () {
              console.log("unsubscribe!");
              sub.unsubscribe();

            });
        },

        publish: $$bus.publish
      };
    },
    enumerable: false
  });

  return $delegate;
}]);
});
```

Considering the following $$bus implementation (kept basic for simplicity):

```
app.factory('$$bus', function () {
  var api = {};
  var events = {};

  api.subscribe = function (event) {
    if (!events.hasOwnProperty(event.name)) {
      events[event.name] = [event];
    } else {
      events[event.name].push(event);
    }
    return {
      unsubscribe: function () {
        api.unsubscribe(event);
      }
    }
  };

  api.publish = function (eventName, data) {
    if (events.hasOwnProperty(eventName)) {
      console.log(eventName);

      angular.forEach(events[eventName], function (subscriber) {
        subscriber.callback.call(this, data);
      });
    }
  };

  api.unsubscribe = function (event) {
    if (events.hasOwnProperty(event.name)) {
      events[event.name].splice(events[event.name].indexOf(event), 1);
      if (events[event.name].length == 0) {
        delete events[event.name];
      }
    }
  };

  return api;
});
```

Now all you have to do is **subscribe** or **publish** events. The unsubscribe will take place automatically (when the $scope is destroyed):

```
  $scope.$bus.subscribe({
    name: 'test', callback: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

And later on publish an event:

```
  $scope.$bus.publish('test', {name: "publishing event!"});
```

An **important** point to make is that the events themselves are subscribed to each individual $scope and not on the $rootScope. That is how you "know" which $scope to release.

I think it answers your question. With that in mind, you can obviously make this mechanism much sophisticated (such as controller event listener released when a view routed, unsubscribe automatically only to certain events, etc.).
Good luck!

** This solution is taken form [Here](http://jonathancreamer.com/an-angular-event-bus-with-postal-js/) which uses a different bus framework (other then that it is the same).

Comment: thanks! this is exactly what I need, this solution is just perfect.